# Return the id of an element using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a function that should return the Id of the element passed in parameters, like :

```
public static Int32 getIdByName(string name)
{
    var query = from student in DataAccess.getInstance.StudentSet
                where student.FirstName.Equals(name)
                select student;

    return toto;
}
```

I don't know how to convert the result `toto` to an Int32 and return it !!

Comment: .Net member names should be UpperCamelCased.

Comment: Do you really expect `FirstName` to map to a single user? How should this return one `int` when multiple students could have the same first name?

Comment: It's not the real code, but the query is supposed to return one student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return DataAccess.getInstance.StudentSet.Last(s => s.FirstName == name).Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Int32 getIdByName(string name)
{
    var query = from student in DataAccess.getInstance.StudentSet
                where student.FirstName.Equals(name)
                select student.Id;

    return query.First();
}
```